# unserialize or array slice?

Tags: php, serialization, slice

What is the correct method to get each block of data from this entry on my database ?

I'm customizing a plugin called custom contact forms for wordpress, and basically for each email received a new entry is created on the database with the following format:

`s:8:"enq_name";s:3:"ICE";s:9:"enq_email";s:23:"xvxvxv@hotmail.com";s:9:"enq_phone";s:10:"9191919191";s:11:"enq_message";s:74:"bla bla bla bla and more bla bla bla";s:10:"enq_footer";s:288:"This message has been set to you by my";`

How can I get individual values like for example the message `enq_message`

Apologies if one or both methods mentioned on the title of the question are wrong, I don't have a clue how to do this :(

Thanks in advance

**Edit:**
Thanks to fulhack I now have this...

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `$table_name` WHERE `data_formid` = $ff ORDER BY `$table_name`.`id` ASC LIMIT 0, 5";     
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo $myDate = date( 'd/M/Y', $row['data_time'] );
    $string = $row['data_value'];

    $serialized = $string;
    $unserialized = unserialize($serialized);
    $theValue = $unserialized['enq_email'];

    echo $theValue;
    }
```

But this only echoes 'e' or more exaclty 'eeeee' since there is for entries on the database.

Answer (score 2):

Try using unserialize() ( http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php ), and then use the key (`enq_message` in your case) to retrieve the value you're looking for.

EDIT: I don't have access to a PHP installation, but I think this would work:

```
$serialized = serialize(array("key" => "value")); // This is the data you supplied
$unserialized = unserialize($serialized);
$theValue = $unserialized["key"];
```

You should probably add some error-checking though.

Comment: Hi, thanks, I just got lost on function mycallback($classname) from the example :(

Comment: I added an example of how I would attempt to use it

Comment: Sorry to bother you... that goes inside the function ?

Comment: Not a problem. No, what you supplied, the long text, is serialized data. This is equivalent to the $serialized variable in my example, so assign your data the name $serialized (or something else) and run unserialize() on it, the return value of unserialize() should be what the data looked like before it was serialized. Now that you have the original data back (an array) - you can index it like it was never serialized. I don't think you need to use a callback (but I may be wrong, I haven't tried this).

Comment: sorry but it didn't work, Thanks again for taking the time. Question had been updated to reflect the code used.

Comment: Hmm, maybe the unserialized array does not contain the key `enq_email`, take a look at the structure of the unserialized data, using var_dump for example. Perhaps you need to supply an integer index instead, such as $unserialized[2].

Comment: var_dump outputs string(8) "enq_name" (repeated 5 times) :)

Comment: Well, then it seems that you have indeed retrieved a value from the array! Finding the correct value is most likely just a case of changing some array index.